# Is there an automatic alternative for creating a barrel for your modules?

Tags: typescript, import, export, auto-generate

I am now using barrels to import 1 file so that I can use all modules in a repository, but I have to type everything manually and that is a lot, so is there any way to make this an automatic procedure or by generating a namespace so that I can import that namespace?

My test barrel:

```
//This is in root/bundles/index.ts
export * from '../src/shapes';
export * from '../src/tests';

//This is in root/src/tests/index.ts
export * from "./test";
export * from "./testu";
export * from "./testo";

//This is in root/src/shapes/index.ts
export * from "./square";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for that called [Barrelsby](https://github.com/bencoveney/barrelsby), however it [has a bug](https://github.com/bencoveney/barrelsby/issues/153) (at the moment of writing) when you run it after having `index.ts` files (it overwrites them and so breaks them). If not for that, it seems like a perfect solution.

What I ended up using is a [Webstorm Barrels Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14990-barrels). There seems to be a similar [solution for VsCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikehanson.auto-barrel) too.

I'd suggest keeping an eye on the library though or maybe even trying to fix the bug (that's what I intend to do, but time is always the issue for most of us). With it you could fully automate the process and even include in your `npm run dev` script, for example.